# Extrato MySql a partir de tabelas ENTRADA e SAIDA

Tags: php, mysql, query, soma

Sou iniciante em MySql e PHP, estou construindo uma aplicação de gerenciamento financeiro para uma instituição beneficente, (trabalho voluntário), e não consigo resolver este problema:

Realizar uma consulta MySql nas tabelas ENTRADA e SAIDA que retorne os resulta como um extrato bancário.

Desde já minha gratidão por sua ajuda. God Bless you!!

Segue as tabelas e resultado esperado:

**01 - TABELA ENTRADA**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `entradas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `mes_referencia` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `conta` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `doador` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valor_entrada` decimal(32,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `n_documento` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2465 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;**
```

**02 - TABELA SAIDA**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `saidas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `mes_referencia` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valor_saida` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `conta` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `favorecido` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cpf` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `categoria` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `numero_doc` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1079 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**03 - RESULTADOS DOS MEUS SONHOS (kkkk)**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: dicas: armazene o saldo anterior e o saldo atual na tabela de movimento... e... justamente, faça uma tabela só de "movimentos" não precisa de duas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há alguns problemas nesse modelo, pode ser que seja apenas de um exercício conceitual, não utilizaria isso em um problema real. Certamente terá problemas com movimentos retroativos ou estornos.

Quando você separa em duas tabelas sendo que o resultado esperado será apenas uma, você adiciona uma complexidade desnecessária, precisando usar UNION na sintaxe, e isso piora ainda mais quando precisa acessar os mesmos dados várias vezes, como também é necessário para calcular os saldos.

Repare que a estrutura dos registros é a mesma, ainda que colocado nomes diferentes nas colunas [doador/favorecido] tudo se trata de uma pessoa relativa ao movimento. Isso também acontece com a coluna de valor, é Colocado [valor_entrada / valor_saida] sendo que se trata do mesmo dado, apenas valor; Ainda tem o uso do sinal +- para indicar se é uma entrada ou saída, que também facilita, se os valores estiverem sinalizados, basta somar todos.

Utilizando a estrutura apresentada, fiz a seguinte Query para extrair os dados desejados:

```
select 
max(data) as data, 
null as documento, 
'Saldo Anterior' as conta,
null as pessoa,
0 as entrada,
0 as saida,
sum(valor) as saldo
from
(select data, valor from entradas where data < '2020-01-01'
union all
select data, valor from saidas where data < '2020-01-01') x

union all

select 
data, documento, conta,pessoa,entrada,saidas, entradas_anteriores - saidas_anteriores + entrada - saidas as saldo
from (
  select 
    id, data, documento, conta, pessoa, valor as entrada, 0     as saidas, (select coalesce(sum(x.valor),0) from entradas x where x.data < e.data) as entradas_anteriores, (select coalesce(sum(x.valor),0) from saidas   x where x.data < e.data) as saidas_anteriores  from entradas e where e.data >= '2020-01-01'

     union all
  select 
    id, data, documento, conta, pessoa, 0     as entrada, valor as saidas, (select coalesce(sum(x.valor),0) from entradas x where x.data < s.data) as entradas_anteriores, (select coalesce(sum(x.valor),0) from saidas   x where x.data < s.data) as saidas_anteriores  from saidas   s where s.data >= '2020-01-01'
) m

order by data;
```

[Você pode ver funcionando no SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a5e1bb/15)

Resultado:

### [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora, utilizando a seguinte estrutura:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `movimentos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `conta` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valor` decimal(32,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pessoa` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `documento` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `saldo_anterior` decimal(32,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `saldo_atual` decimal(32,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2465 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Com a seguinte query posso ter o mesmo resultado:

```
select 
x.data,
null as documento,
'Saldo Anterior' as conta,
null as pessoa,
0 as valor,
x.saldo_atual
from movimentos x
where x.data < '2020-01-01'

union all

select 
m.data,
m.documento,
m.conta,
m.pessoa,
m.valor,
m.saldo_atual
from movimentos m
where m.data >= '2020-01-01'
```

> Mais simples não!?

Segue o [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/314445/2)

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Observações:

Eu não colocaria pra exibir o saldo anterior como uma linha do resultado, possivelmente seria exibido em outro local na tela, assim como o somatório total.

Nesse exemplo ainda há problema para o caso de movimento retroativo.

Comment: Olá, querido amigo @Rovann Linhalis
Meu **muito obrigado** por sua generosidade em usar um pouco do seu precioso tempo para me ajudar. De fato sua explicação **me ajudou bastante!**
como já tenho um sistema rodando onde há varios registro em 2 tabelas. Resolvi usar o seu primeiro exemplo.
OK, funcionou, mas tenho ainda um problema; AS ENTRADAS SÃO LISTADAS NA CONSULTA E SE REPETEM COMO SAÍDAS, JÁ AS SAÍDAS NÃO SÃO LISTADAS.
Segue aqui o MEU CÓDIGO REAL
[Meu código é este aqui]( http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72e0aac/1)
Caso possa me ajudar ainda agradeço muitíssimo!
Fica com Deus!

Comment: @Maggy no select dos pagamentos, você continuou usando a tabela de lancamentos... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72e0aac/8

Comment: Uau!!! Valeu!!
Realmente, pronto. resolvido. obrigado mais uma vez

Comment: Deixo aqui meus parabéns a esta maravilhosa comunidade, e especialmente a você @Rovann Linhalis pela pronta atenção, sua explicação foi excelente e fundamental pra resolver meu problema. Vc é nota 1000!!

Deus te recompense

Obrigada, Obrigada!!

Comment: @Maggy, por nada, seja bem vinda e disponha, mas observe que há algumas regras na comunidade, como não usar o campo de respostas para fazer comentários ou complementar as perguntas, você pode editar a pergunta ou usar o campo de comentários. Se estiver com dúvida sobre isso também, há bastante material na comunidade e também fique a vontade para perguntar (lá no meta: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Ok. entendido. Obrigada